# Add a class when click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a block which has some elements. I did that elements will get new styles if I add a some class to this block. SO, can you help me with code in jQuery which add a class to my "infoBlock".

Ihave a  but need

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  }

.infoBlock {
 display: block;
 width: 520px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #fff;
 margin: 50px 0 0 225px;
 position: relative;

}

.infoBlock .more {
 width: 180px;
 height: 40px;
 display: inline-block;
 background: #5795f9;
 text-decoration: none;
 font: bold 16px Helvetica;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 10px ;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 20px 0 0 0;
color: #fff;
}

.infoBlock .person{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 25%;
}

.infoBlock .person img {
 width: 80%;
 margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.infoBlock .person ul {
 margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.infoBlock .person .risk {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #a6a6a6;
 font: bold 15px Helvetica;
}

.infoBlock .person .level {
 margin: 10px 0 0 ;
 color: #ff8080;
 font: bold 14px Helvetica;
}

.infoBlock .personDescription {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 74%;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.infoBlock .personDescription .name{
 font:bold 20px Helvetica;
 color: #a6a6a6;
 margin: 0 0 20px;
}
.infoBlock .personDescription .position {
 font: bold 15px Helvetica;
 color: #5795f9;
 margin: 0 0 25px;
}

.infoBlock .personDescription .description {
 font: bold 14px Helvetica;
 color: #a6a6a6;
}
.infoBlock .personDescription .description span {
 color: #5795f9;
}
.infoBlock .personDescription .description .black {
 color: #000;
}

.infoBlock .fullInfo {
 display: none;
}
/* //////////////////////////// */

.infoBlock.f {
 height: 480px;
}

.infoBlock.f .fullInfo {
 display: block;
}

.infoBlock.f .person ul{
 position: absolute;
 margin: -115px 0 0 450px;

}

.infoBlock.f .personDescription .description {
 display: none;
}

.infoBlock.f .border {
 width: 80%;
 height: 1px;
 background-color: #a4a4a4;
 margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
 position: absolute;
}

.infoBlock.f .personDescription .more{
 display: none;
}

.infoBlock.f .fullInfo {
 position: absolute;
 margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
}

.infoBlock.f .fullInfo .infoMenu li:hover {
 color: #5795f9;
}

.infoBlock.f .fullInfo .infoMenu li{
 display: inline;
 margin:0 30px 0 0;
 color: #a6a6a6;
 font: bold 14px Helvetica;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.infoBlock.f .fullInfo .scheme .schemeNumber {
 margin: 20px 0 8px 30px;
 font: bold 15px Arial;
 color: #000;
}



.infoBlock.f .fullInfo .scheme .chance {
 margin:0 0 10px 30px;
 font: 16px Arial;
 font-weight: 200;
 color: #000;
}
.infoBlock.f .fullInfo .scheme table {
 margin: 0 0 10px 28px;
}

.infoBlock.f .fullInfo .scheme table p {
 font: bold 15px Helvetica; 
}
.infoBlock.f .fullInfo .scheme table .type {
 color: #a5a5a5;
 font: 15px Helvetica;
}

.infoBlock.f .fullInfo .scheme .problem {
 font: 16px Arial;
 color: #a5a5a5;
 margin: 0 0 20px 30px;
}

.infoBlock.f .fullInfo .scheme .more {
 margin:  0 0 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "infoBlock">

      <div class = "person">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt = "">
        <ul>
          <li><p class = "risk">авыаыа:</p></li>
          <li><p class = "level">Висоцуацуацуааукий</p></li>
          <li></li>

        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class = "personDescription">
        <h2 class = "name">Василенко<br> Василь Антипович</h2>

        <h4 class = "position">Авыпукпуфппук</h4>

        <p class = "description">АВаываывавыпкупк <span>2х схем<br></span> на сумму більш ніж <span class = "black">3 млн. грн<span></p>
        <a href="#" class = "more" >докладніше</a>

      </div>


      <div class = "fullInfo">
        <ul class = "infoMenu">
          <li>Схеми</li>
          <li>Зв'язки</li>
          <li>Додаткова інформація</li>
        </ul>

        <div class = "scheme">
          <h3 class = "schemeNumber">Схема №1.1</h3>
          <p class = "chance">Вірогідність - 93%</p>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td><p>Тип:</p></td>  
              <td><p class = "type">авыавыавыавыа</p></td>
            </tr>

          </table>

          <p class = "problem">Квартира площею 123 кв. м записана<br> на Василенко М.В. (теща)</p>

          <a href="#" class = "more f" >докладніше</a>
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simiply do this with the following code snippet:

```
$('.more').on('click', function() {
    $('.infoBlock').addClass('class');
});
```

Where `'class'` will be the desired class name that holds the new properties.

Here is a working **[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/0vzLgv0p/)**

Comment: thanks a lot, to delete this class I have to use this funtion:

$(".more").on("click", function() {
  if ( $(this).parents(".infoBlock").hasClass("f")) {
        $(this).parents(".infoBlock").removeClass("f");
  }
})